# Why didn't Twilight notice the cause of her friends changes sooner?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

In A Return to Harmony, for the vast majority of the time that the rest of the Mane 6 are greyish, Twilight seems to not notice and think they've just had a change of heart somehow. This being in the face of them more or less having complete personality flips and quite obviously losing a majority of their color. Is it an oversight by the writers or was Twilight actually aware and just not sure what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite being one of the worst of the new series (in my opinion), I don't think this was a production issue. I think the visual clue was more of a hint for the viewer and wasn't meant to be as obvious to Twilight.

The personality flips on the other hand should have been spotted. Twilight isn't the most social pony however, and may have missed it under the extreme pressure of trying to save the world. In fact, had she noticed, she may have assumed it wasn't a change but merely a response of her fellow ponies to the stress of the situation.

Comment: D: the Q episode being the worst of the new series? Really?

Comment: Also,  Pinkie comments on her color change once she's restored to normal: [`Pinkie Pie: [laughing] And I-I turned gray! [giggles] Can you believe it?! `](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Transcripts/The_Return_of_Harmony_Part_2)

Comment: It didn't have the same feel to as the others, Twilight became stupid for a while. It really picks up after Ep5.

Comment: Yeah, i suppose. I still say Lesson Zero is in top 10 just for how silly the antics get :P

Comment: Yeah...That one.

Comment: Twilight *did* notice the personality flips and *did* attribute them to stress.  [Example](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Transcripts/The_Return_of_Harmony_Part_1): "What do you suppose has [Pinkie] so upset? It's not like her. ... Better pick up the pace before the stress of this gets the better of all of us."  Also, later: "This awful labyrinth is getting to everypony."

Comment: @RCIX Pinkie Pie breaks the fourth wall all the time, so you shouldn't take her comments to be representative of what's going on in-universe :)

Comment: @Tacroy: Good point. Hmm....

Comment: @jwodder: expand it to an answer perhaps?

Comment: The color change isn't just for the viewer. Spike makes a comment about it to Twilight.

Comment: @Tacroy: Rewatched the episode, and Spike also notices it: `Spike: Twilight, what's going on? Why does everybody look so...gray? `